# Does dragon dictate 2.0 for OSX support Spanish?

Tags: macos

I am about to buy dragon dictate 2.0, but I would need to dictate both in english and in spanish.

I remember seeing somewhere that various languages were supported, but I can't find it anymore and I'm worried that it will only support english now.

Comment: It's not obvious from their website; did you consider just emailing/calling their sales division and asking?

Comment: I tried but their webpage is stuck in 1990's hell: sparse information, broken links, no contact us, no way to email or phone them, no way to use the forum without buying the product and registering the license key.

Answer (score 2):

Their explicitly [multi-lingual product](http://www.macspeech.com/pages.php?pID=193) "only" supports English, French, Italian, and German. In a [press release from 2009](http://www.macspeech.com/article_info.php?articles_id=335), they mention that Spanish language support is being worked on, but no news since then.

---

You might be able to find older copies of the [discontinued](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IListen) [iListen and its Spanish LanguagePak](http://www.macspeech.com/article_info.php?articles_id=100).

Comment: January 2014, still no Spanish for Dragon Dictate.